# Point Group of a pattern

Tags: symmetric-groups, solution-verification, pattern-recognition

I need to determine the point group of the following patterns: [image]

I think the one on the left is $D_1$ and the one on the right is $D_2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine which wallpaper group you have, first identify the unit cell and symmetry operations for your images:

[image: Symmetry and unit cell]

Then use the [Wallpaper group diagram](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Wallpaper_group_diagrams):

[image: Wallpaper group diagram]

Both images have a maximum of 2-fold rotations and simple reflections. The left image has no perpendicular reflections, making it *pmg*. The right image has perpendicular reflections with an off-axis rotocenter, making it *cmm*.

Both of these latices have $D_2$ point groups at the center of the cell, as well as lower-order point groups at other points.

Comment: I somehow didn't notice that this question is 4 years old. I hope you figured it out before now!