# Determining a fixed point

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order $14$, and let $S$ be a set of order $5$ on which $G$ operates. Prove that there is a fixed point, an element $s$ of $S$ that is left fixed by every element of $G$.

Comment: Orbit decomposition of $S$.

Comment: @DanielFischer You mean to decompose S into orbits of order 1 ?

Comment: Not all orbits will have order $1$ in general. But what orders can the orbits possibly have?

Comment: @DanielFischer Can you perhaps help me with this? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542669/point-group-of-a-pattern

Answer (score 1):

By the Orbit-Stabilizer theorem, for any $x\in S$, you know that
$$
|O(x)||Stab(x)| = 14 \Rightarrow |O(x)| \in \{1,2\}
$$
(since $|O(x)| \leq |S| = 5$). Hence, there must exists $x_0 \in S$ such that
$$
|O(x_0)| = 1\Rightarrow |Stab(x_0)| = 14 \Rightarrow Stab(x_0) = G
$$

Comment: Could you help me with this as well ? Nobody answered me since yesterday: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542669/point-group-of-a-pattern