# Hypercube and dihedral group

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, abstract-algebra

Let $G_n$ denote the subgroup of the orthogonal group $O_n$ of elements that send the hypercube to itself, the group of symmetries $C_n$, including the orientation-reversing symmetries.

It would like to show that $G_2$ is isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_4$ of order 8

I determined a formula for the order of $G_n$ which is $n!2^n$. Therefore, we already notice that both sets have the same order.

Comment: 1. It is not clear what $C_n$ is and how it is different from $G_n$. 2. Group theorists often denote by $C_n$ the cyclic group of order $n$, so this is confusing. 3. When you say $D_4$, please specify what you mean: the dihedral group of order $4$ or of order $8$, because different authors use different notation.

Comment: $C_n$ is the hypercube not the cyclic group.

Comment: Now the answer depends on the exact definition of the dihedral group $D_4$ that you use. Some people just define it as the group of symmetries of a square, in which case the problem is trivial.

Comment: I edited above based on your comment

Comment: I see, and my second comment is still relevant.

Comment: @DanShved I don't understand. Do you need another specification ?

Comment: Yes. Here are several ways to define $D_4$: (i) $D_4$ is the group of symmetries of a square. (ii) $D_4$ is the semidirect product of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, where the latter acts on the former by taking inverses. (iii) $D_4$ is specified by generators and relations as $\langle a, b \mid a^4 = 1, b^2 = 1, b^{-1}ab = a^{-1} \rangle$. (iv) Your variant. The exact answer to your problem depends on which definition you want to use.

Comment: Definition 3 is the one I am using

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment. OK, so, the one with generators and relations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, we have established that your definition of $D_4$ is
$$
D_4 = \langle a, b \mid a^4 = b^2 = 1, b^{-1} a b = a^{-1} \rangle.
$$

Now, in the group $G_2$ choose $A$ to be a rotation by 90 degrees and $B$ to be a mirror reflection. Clearly, there are such $A$ and $B$ in $G_2$. It is also clear that $G_2$ is generated by $A$ and $B$.

To prove that $G_2$ is isomorphic to $D_4$, we will build homomorphisms $\varphi: D_4 \to G_2$ and $\psi: G_2 \to D_4$ that are inverses of each other.

To build $\varphi: D_4 \to G_2$, let us note that in group $G_2$ elements $A$ and $B$ satisfy these relations: $A^4 = 1$, $B^2 = 1$, $B^{-1} A B = A^{-1}$ (check this by hand). It follows that there exists a unique homomorphism $\varphi: D_4 \to G_2$ that sends $a$ to $A$ and $b$ to $B$.

Now let us build $\psi: G_2 \to D_4$. Note that every element $C \in G_2$ can be represented as $C = A^m B^n$. Define $\psi(C) = a^m b^n$.

First of all, we need to check that this definition is correct. If we represent $C$ in two different ways, $C = A^m B^n = A^{m'} B^{n'}$, we need to check that the same value is assigned to $\psi(C)$, i.e. $a^m b^n = a^{m'} b^{n'}$. Indeed, if $A^m B^n = A^{m'} B^{n'}$, then $A^{m-m'} = B^{n'-n}$. $A$ preserves orientation and $B$ doesn't. It follows that $n-n'$ is even, so $A^{m-m'}=1$, so $m-m'$ is a multiple of $4$. But then $$a^{m'}b^{n'} = a^m a^{m'-m} b^n b^{n'-n} = a^m b^n,$$ because $a^4 = b^2 = 1$ in $D_4$. So map $\psi$ is defined correctly.

We also need to check that $\psi$ is a homomorphism. This is quite mundane and involves a little case analysis, so I will omit the check.

Now that we have built $\psi$ and $\varphi$, we see that $\psi\varphi(a) = a$ and $\psi\varphi(b) = b$, so $\psi\varphi$ is the identity map of $D_4$. In a similar way $\varphi\psi$ is the identity map of $G_2$. It follows that $\psi$ and $\varphi$ are inverses of each other, so they are isomorphisms, qed.

Comment: Can you help me with this ? Nobody answered me for a couple of days

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542669/point-group-of-a-pattern

Comment: I wonder if one is permitted to simply observe that upon examining the sets of generators of $\mathcal{C}_2$ and $D_4$, it turns out that they are equivalent, hence the isomorphism between the two. It boils down to whether or not specifying set of generators (plus law of composition) as in the case of the definition of $D_4$ already determines the group unambiguously, anyway, what else can there be to make $\mathcal{C}_2$ different if we have already discovered the full structure of its generators?